# Prime factorisation in java

Tags: java, performance, time-limit-exceeded, factors

I came across this question in a coding contest (Java-restricted) and I got TLE. I am unable to provide the link of the question as the contest is closed now. Can I know how can I optimise this?

> Four Functions
>
> Given four functions
>
> - A(x) = Number of i where 1 <= i <= x and gcd(i,x) = 1
> - B(x) = Sum of A(d) where d divides the number x
> - C(x) = Sum of exponents of each prime in the prime factorization of B(x)
> - D(x) = Sum of C(i) where 1 <= i <= x
>
> If $$B(x) = {p_1} ^ {a1} {p_2} ^ {a2} {p_3} ^ {a3}$$
> where p1,p2,p3 are prime factors of B(x), then C(x) is a1 + a2
>
> Find the value of D(N) Constraints:
>
> $$1 \le testcases \le 1000000$$
>
> $$1 \le N \le 1000000$$
>
> Example :
>
> Input :
>
> 1
>
> 4
>
> Output :
>
> 4
>
> For n = 4
>
> $$C(1) = 0$$
>
> $$C(2) = 1$$
>
> $$C(3) = 1$$
>
> $$C(4) = 2$$
>
> $$D(4) = C(1) + C(2) + C(3) + C(4) = 4$$

This is my approach

```
public class Main {
    static long commonDivisor(long num1,long num2) {
        if(num1 == 0) {
            return num2;
        }
        return commonDivisor(num2 % num1, num1);
    }

    static long funcA(long numb) {
        long answer = numb;
        for (long itr = 2; itr * itr <= numb; itr++) {
            if(numb % itr == 0) {
                while(numb % itr == 0) {
                    numb /= itr;
                }
                answer -= answer / itr;
            }
        }
        if(numb > 1) {
            answer -= answer / numb;
        }
        return answer;
    }
    static long funcB(long numb) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (long itr = 1; itr <= Math.sqrt(numb); itr++){
            if (numb % itr == 0){
                if(numb/itr == itr){
                    sum = sum + funcA(itr);
                } else {
                    sum = sum + funcA(itr) + funcA(numb/itr);
                }
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
    static boolean check_prime(long numb) {
        BigInteger bigint = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(numb)); 
        return bigint.isProbablePrime(1); 
    }
    static long funcC(long numb) {
        if (numb <= 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        long remNum = numb;
        long expo = 0;
        for (long itr = 2; itr <= Math.sqrt(numb); itr++) {
             if(check_prime(itr)) {
                while (remNum % itr == 0) {
                    expo++;
                    remNum /= itr;
                }
             } 
        }
        if(check_prime(remNum)) {
            if (remNum > 1) {
                expo++;
            }
        }
        return expo;
    }
    static long funcD(long numb) {
         long result = 0;
         for(long itr = 1; itr <= numb; itr++){
             result += funcC(funcB(itr));
         }
         return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));    
        long testCases = Long.parseLong(buffer.readLine());
        for(long itr = 1; itr <= testCases; itr++) {
            long number = Long.parseLong(buffer.readLine());
            System.out.println(funcD(number));
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cross-posted: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/245127/65105, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62777612/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a coding contest, the answer is almost never to implement the problem the same way as it is given.

For example here, functions A and B are actually intentionally misleading. Function A is also known as Euler's Totient, and function B computes the sum of totients of divisors which [is the same as the original number](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Euler_Phi_Function_over_Divisors). Detailed review of them is therefore a waste, functions A and B don't need to be implemented at all.

Function C can be improved by noting that the lowest divisor of a number is necessarily a prime, so calling `check_prime` is unnecessary. If `itr` was `a * b` then `a` and `b` would have been found first and divided out of `remNum` already, making `itr` not a divisor of `remNum`.
The square root is also unnecessary, and relatively expensive. It can be avoided by testing `itr * itr <= numb` instead. There is no risk of overflow given that `numb <= 1000000`. Further refinements are possible.

Function D can be improved by caching the partial sums. In isolation that would not help, but there can be multiple test cases during a run of the program, and they can reuse the previously computed sums. For example as an extreme case, after the test case `1000000` has been used, any further test cases could be essentially free, because all possible cases would have been calculated at that point. Also, after `funcD(10)` has been evaluated, `funcD(20)` could start with that result instead of starting over from scratch.

Comment: Just an addendum to the last part. The function $D$ can also be simplified. The function $C$ satisfies the logarithmic property $C(a)+C(b)=C(ab)$. Therefore $D(n)=C(n!)$. Now, $C(n!)$ can be computed using [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) by computing the primes up to $n$ and applying the formula to compute their exponents (or valuations) in the factorization of $n!$.